# using variables in find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm really new to rails, but I'm trying to pull some data that matches user preferences (current_user.industry) for example.

Is there a standard practice in rails for pulling data using SQL and using variables from helpers, or other `@variables` ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to escaping variables in `find_by_sql` statements?

You can do

```
Model.find_by_sql("SELECT .... ?", @var)
```

just like you do in `.where`.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks - but I'm getting: 

`wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Answer (score 5):

Model.find_by_sql(["SELECT .... ?", @var])

enclose sql query in []